# Ldap DN (distinguished name) with more than one CN. What is the purpose?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi, openldap

I would ideally think that a entry in ldap would have only one CN. But when I saw this entry - `CN=username,CN=Users,DC=wmservice,DC=corpnet1,DC=com`, i started thinking what is the purpose of allowing more than one common name to a entry.
Can some one explain.

I am really new to ldap, so please bear with me.

Comment: ok, if am right... this has got to do just with the hierarchy... above the entry  `cn=username` there is a entry with `cn=Users`. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple CN is used for a hierarchical purpose,say you have two departments finance and engineering, both the departments can have same users so we can distinguish it in hierarchy system.
Here is a thread that discusses similar concern:
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201105/msg00181.html

Comment: This does not explain how or why two elements in the hierarchy can have a `cn` attribute

Comment: Why couldn't two elements in a hierarchy have cn attribute?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't capitalize what shouldn't be, the entry you saw is actually:
`cn=username,cn=Users,dc=wmservice,dc=corpnet1,DC=com`

Second, the tree where you've found it is kinda bad.
`cn=username` should be `uid=username`.
The reason for this is that `cn` (which is short for `commonName`) is better (and more often) utilized as a display string. Users rightly expect that their displayed names could have accented characters, spaces, which would lead to problems in DNs (ugly ecaping, etc.).
At the end of the day: `cn` is `commonName` which word in English - for me - means it shouldn't be used in IDs, technical texts, etc...

Now, here is a big answer for your question:
https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/
TLDR: there is **no more than one cn to your entry**
Your entry has one `cn`, but its parent have one tool